# Facebook Mobile page tab error: This page is for an app that doesn't work on mobile devices (tried ref=ts)

Tags: facebook, mobile, ref

Previously I was able to get to my app on my Page Tab on mobile devices by appending ?ref=ts to the end of the app url on the page tab. Suddenly this has stopped working and i am now getting the following error message when trying on the iphone/android facebook apps:

"This page is for an app that doesn't work on mobile devices. Please try visiting it the next time you use Facebook on your computer"

Has anyone come across this issue and does anyone know what I can do to solve this problem please.

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in the past as well and just realized it was no longer working. I found a little work around but who knows how long it'll work.... I created a bitly link and redirect through there. Worked for me.